# parse.com list users that don't have relations with current user

Tags: php, facebook, parse-platform

I can list the users that have relations of a current user, but how do I list users that don't have relations with the current user. Or how do I exclude users that have relations with the current user from a list. I am happy to see it in javascript, ios etc..

```
$user = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();  
$relation = $user->getRelation("follow");
$usersFollowed = $relation->getQuery()->find();
print_r($usersFollowed);
```

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention, the relation is set up on the _User class to the _User class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using php, but you could try to use `notEqualTo` constraint to 'follow' with current user.

Something like `query.notEqualTo('follow', Parse.User.current());` in js

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around to achieve what I wanted to achieve. I am happy for others to improve it.

```
$user = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();  
$relation = $user->getRelation("follow");
$usersFollowed = $relation->getQuery()->find();

// loop through all the users that are being followed
for ($i = 0; $i < count($usersFollowed); $i++) {
    $object = $usersFollowed[$i];
    $usernames = $object->get('username');

    // concatenate the usernames to produce a string
    $str_usernames .= $usernames . ' '; 
}


// convert the string into an array
$array_usernames = explode(" ", $str_usernames);
print_r($array_usernames);
echo "<br><br>";

// query all the usernames not contained in the above array
$query = new ParseQuery("_User");
$query->notContainedIn("username", $array_usernames);
$results = $query->find();
print_r($results);
```

I hope this helps others, it costs two api requests. I am not sure how it would perform over thousands or hundreds of thousands of usernames though.